# Integral factor for an easy ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ODE:
$$2y(x^2-1)dy=x(x^2+y^2-1)dx$$

This ODE is not exact and:
$$\partial_x N-\partial_y M=-6xy$$
so Integral factor is 
$$\mu(x)=e^{\int \frac{-6xy}{2y(x^2-1)}dx}=(x^2-1)^{-3}$$

but I couldn't find a function $F$ s.t.

$$\partial_x F=x(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-3},\quad \partial_y F=2y(x^2-1)^{-2}.$$

any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equation for $\mu$ is inconsistent - you appear to have lost a factor in the integration. $$\int\frac{-6xy}{2y(x^2-1)}\,dx=-\frac32\int\frac{2x}{x^2-1}\,dx=-\frac32\ln(x^2-1)\\\implies\mu(x)=(x^2-1)^{-3/2}$$This then fixes your problem. You need to find an $F$ such that $$\partial_y F=-2y(x^2-1)^{-1/2}\implies F=-y^2(x^2-1)^{-1/2}+f(x)\\\partial_xF=(x^3+xy^2-x)(x^2-1)^{-3/2}\implies F=(x^2-y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-1/2}+g(y)$$Combining, $g(y)=0$. $$F(x,y)=(x^2-y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-1/2}$$

Comment: Are you sure that you have not a typo? $-y^2$ or $+y^2$?

Comment: $$\begin{align}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}((x^2-y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-1/2})&=2x(x^2-1)^{-1/2}-x(x^2-y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-3/2}\\&=(2x^3-2x-x^3+xy^2+x)(x^2-1)^{-3/2}\\&=x(x^2+y^2-1)(x^2-1)^{-3/2}\end{align}$$So I think integrating $\partial_x F$ to give that for $F$ is certainly correct

Answer (score 1):

Let $$v(x)=y(x)^2$$ then we get
$$\frac{d v(x)}{dx}-\frac{x v(x)}{x^2-1}=x$$ 
and multiply by $$\mu(x)=e^{\int-\frac{x}{x^2-1}dx}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$$
The solution is given by $$y(x)=\pm \sqrt{c_1 \sqrt{x^2-1}+x^2-1}$$